# Android GridView cell color Background

Tags: android, gridview, colors

If the cell of GridView is pressed, I want to change the background color. The code that I created works, but when pressed another cell has to change color the selected cell and all others must not have any background color.
Thanks for your help.

```
 elenco_ore.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
             public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
                                     int position, long id) {

                 List<String> lList = Arrays.asList(orari);
                 Iterator<String> iterator = lList.iterator();
                 while (iterator.hasNext()) {
                     String orari_array = (iterator.next());
                     if(orari_array != (((TextView) v).getText())){
                     ((TextView) v).setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
                 }else{
                     ((TextView) v).setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);

                     }
                 }

             }
         });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can modify your grid view for single choice as-

```
<GridView
       ...
       android:choiceMode="singleChoice" />
```

And the selector as

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item android:state_focused="true"
          android:drawable="@drawable/grid_item_pressed" />
    <item android:state_pressed="true"
          android:drawable="@drawable/grid_item_pressed" />
    <item android:state_selected="true"
          android:state_activated="true"
          android:drawable="@drawable/grid_item_selected" />
    <item android:state_activated="true"
          android:drawable="@drawable/grid_item_selected" />
    <item android:state_selected="true"
          android:drawable="@android:color/black" />
    <item android:drawable="@android:color/transparent" />
</selector>
```

And no need to worry rest of the things android will manage automatically the states of items.